# How do I improve benchmark accuracy in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, benchmarking

I am looking for a way to benchmark the performance of a function in Javascript, so that I can optimise it more effectively. The resulting number (average tick duration) should be accurate across runs/tests, ideally no more than 2% deviation between runs, but the code I have written frequently has a deviation of more than 30%.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
let j = 0;
while (true) {
   // Collect garbage from previous run
   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      global.gc();
   }
   
   // Reset the board state
   Board.reset();

   // Seed the random number generator
   SRandom.seed(40404040404);
   
   Board.setup();
   SERVER.setup();

   // Warm up the JIT
   for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      SERVER.tick();
   }
   
   const numTicks = 5000;
   
   const startTime = performance.now();

   for (let i = 0; i < numTicks; i++) {
      SERVER.tick();
   }

   const timeElapsed = performance.now() - startTime;
   const averageTickTimeMS = timeElapsed / numTicks;
   console.log("(#" + (j + 1) + ") Average tick MS: " + averageTickTimeMS);
   j++;
}
```

The code runs on node JS, and when I run it I close as many other programs as I can, typically leaving only chrome, VSCode (what I use to run the code), and a terminal open.

This does benchmark a game, so there is a lot of random number generation involved, but before the benchmark I override the built-in Math.random with a seeded random number generator (`Math.random = () => SRandom.next()`) and re-seed it each run.

Below is an output of when I run the benchmark:

```
(#1) Average tick MS: 4.773744156002999
(#2) Average tick MS: 3.103633259952068
(#3) Average tick MS: 3.431657537043095
(#4) Average tick MS: 3.3931038970351217
(#5) Average tick MS: 3.557662303030491
(#6) Average tick MS: 3.6041946840286254
(#7) Average tick MS: 3.570515029013157
(#8) Average tick MS: 3.8610670589804648
(#9) Average tick MS: 3.758602159976959
(#10) Average tick MS: 3.6722980710268023
```

I am not sure why the first run takes so much longer, but excluding that run there is a deviation of 24% between run 2 and run 8.

What can I do to make the benchmark more accurate? Or is this a fundamental limitation of Javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting stable timing results is hard (in my experience). You may want to try a package like [benchmark](https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark), that handles some of the averaging and statistics for you. (If nothing else, you could take a look at what it does for ideas.)

Answer (score 0):

If JS code doesn't depend on Network/DOM I suggest to get a minimum value. Otherwise you can't control deviations, but you can again get minimum, maximum and average values.

Also note that make a benchmark for 5ms isn't very informative, try to loop your logic so your 1 benchmark run would be at least 100ms. Then divide the benchmark time by number of the loops.

In my benchmark I try to hit a minimum value with looping estimated automatically:

```js
// @benchmark Array.join()
let count = 100000;
const arr = [];
while(count--) arr.push('0');
arr.join('');

// @benchmark String concat
{
let count = 100000;
let str = ''
while(count--) str +='0';
str;
}

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: I do use a loop in my code, the function I'm profiling runs 5000 times (numTicks variable) and then the total time is divided by 5000 to get the average.

Comment: I've tried out taking the minimum and maximum and the minimum is much more accurate than the average, but I'm a bit concerned with how useful the number is for profiling purposes, as I mostly just care about the average time for the function to run. Would the minimum still be a useful metric?

Comment: @eggpoison minimum is the most useful for comparing, for example you could change code and compare with the old version thus making code faster and faster by benchmarking while developing

Comment: @eggpoison adding more ticks will get more stable numbers